# Running & sharing data between two functions simultaneously using "threading" & "queue" module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two function (func_1 & func_2). I want to run that two functions simultaneously but in different threads using the "threading" module. Now I want to use the result from func_1 to func_2 recursively. For example, func_1 downloading images from the website continuously and sends those images to func_2 and then func_2 process those images continuously & save those processed images in local drive. That's what my aim is. I'm new to Python so could somebody explain how to do it. I've some sample a program so that it will be clear what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

```
def func_1():
    while True:
        #downloading images from net & sends to func_2

def func_2():
    #getting result from func_1 and process them recursively

t1=threading.Thread(target=func_1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=func_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Roy,

I'm myself not the biggest threading specialist, but I would like to stress some parts in your question, which are unclear or phony (for me personaly):

> Now I want to use the result from func_1 to func_2 recursively.

This is not a recursion, but the so called **producer-consumer** or some type of **synchronization** thread. To be more precise I've looked at the precise recursion definition in [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recursive):

> relating to, or constituting a procedure that can repeat itself indefinitely

which wouldn't be the pure meaning in this case.

> func_1 downloading images from the website continuously and sends those images to func_2 and then func_2 process those images continuously ..

Does it mean that your **thread1** shouldn't wait for the successful processing in **thread2** ? If so I suggest you to look at [this page](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#basic-synchronization-using-lock) under *Producer-Consumer*.

Actually the whole article is very good in my opinion, good luck :)